# Google Docs in Midori

Tags: midori

When I try to open Google Docs in Midori, I just get the "loading" spinner. The app never actually loads. I've tried switching to each of the built-in user agents, but with no success.

Is there anything that I can do to get Google Docs to work in Midori?

[image: Here's what I'm seeing.]

Comment: It said the browser is not supported for me so I installed chrome/firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Midori is not supported by Drive & Docs. I emulated Firefox with Midori without success.

Here the Requirements:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en

Comment: Thank you! This document mentions that Chrome 23 and Safari 6 are unsupported, so maybe a new version of Midori will update WebKitGTK+ and get Docs working again.

Comment: Midori 0.6.0 is under development. GTK3 & WebKit2 should be used by default. Maybe it's working in the new version. https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/898496